# Finding an Annotation associated with an IMarker

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm making a plugin with a text replacement component like Eclipse's QuickFix. The offsets that I'm using (pulled from marker.getAttribute) are wrong when changes have been made, but not saved. I understand that this is just due to the way that markers function.

When markers are added to a Resource, they attach an Annotation to the document's annotation model. This annotation does keep track of unsaved changes, so it would be more appropriate for me to pull my offsets from its position instead of the marker.

Is there a way for me, given a marker, to find the Annotation that is tied to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations don't track their position directly. The position is maintained by the annotation model class (`IAnnotationModel`).

You can get the annotation model from the editor `ISourceViewer`

```
IAnnotatorModel model = viewer.getAnnotationModel();
```

You then have to search the model annotation for the marker annotation you want and get its position from the model:

```
Iterator<?> iter = model.getAnnotationIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  Object object = iter.next();
  if (object instanceof MarkerAnnotation) {
    MarkerAnnotation annotation = (MarkerAnnotation)object;

    IMarker marker = annotation.getMarker();

    // TODO check this is the marker you are interested in

    Position position = model.getPosition(annotation);
  }
}
```

Comment: Alright thanks for clarifying, but is there any link between an IMarker and a MarkerAnnotation? In other words, if I have an IMarker can I somehow know which MarkerAnnotation I'm interested in? I can't compare the offsets of the IMarker, since they aren't updated until the resource is saved.

Comment: MarkerAnnotation has a `getMarker()` method - added to answer.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, not sure how I overlooked it. Thanks!